# Jenkins sed Terraform shell

Tags: jenkins, sed, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins pipeline that I need to run a `sed` on a file but I am getting an error of `line 2: syntax error: unexpected ")"`

My file is this:-

```
name=""
age=""
```

My Jenkins sh line is:

```
"""sed -i -e 's|(name *= *")"|\1${params.NAME}"|g' -e 's|(age *= *")"|\1${params.AGE}"|g' vars.txt"""
```

I can run the `sed` on my shell fine and it works, but Jenkins doesn't like it for some reason.

If I run it through the Jenkins Pipeline Syntax Generator I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You are using BRE POSIX pattern, and to create a capturing group there, you need to use escaped parentheses, `\(...\)`. However, in the triple-quoted string literal, you need to escape the backslash to get a literal backslash in the resulting string.

You need to fix the line you have like this:

```
'''sed -i' ' -e 's|\\(name *= *"\\)"|\\1'"${params.NAME}"'"|g' -e 's|\\(age *= *"\\)"|\\1'"${params.AGE}"'"|g' vars.txt'''
```

Comment: That doesn't work either. I still get the `unexpected ')'` error

Comment: @Luke Add `' '` right after `-i` (as I updated just now).

Comment: Still the same issue

Comment: @Luke Please try the updated command, I replaced with the triple single quoted string literal. If it does not work, try replacing all ``\\`` with ``\``.